# FBSDKAccessToken iOS SDK , identify a unique user for data

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using Facebook login OAuth for my app. The reason behind posting this question is uniquely identify the Facebook id , by using userID or access token.

The data will be stored in a database, and should be uniquely identifiable for that Facebook logged-in user.

The `currentAccessToken` does change and we can configure a notification(`FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification`) when it changes.

So, I confused, that should I use userId or accessToken.

As, in case if user deletes the app. and wants the data back for the app. there should be unique identifier for that user.

So, will the following flow work or am I missing anything.
[image]

Comment: You should use `accessToken` to fetch user data by calling facebook graph API, and there you will get user `ID`.

Comment: I am using Facebook login just to validate a user. The app. is mean to be Social and some data will be stored on other server.

Comment: Use user ID by calling facebook graph API.... You should send accessToken to the server on login. Server calls facebook graph API, gets the user id, check if user exists in database ....

Answer (score 0):

> The data will be stored in a database, and should be uniquely identifiable for that Facebook logged-in user.

Use the user ID then. Your login flow seems fine.

---

Note that there are multiple ways of do this.

- The client logs in and sends the access token to the server, then the server fetches the data.
- The client logs in and fetches the data, then sends the data to the server.

You'd want to use the first method if the data needs to be reliable.